# Checking if an item can be placed with Minecraft Forge 1.8.9

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to check if an item can be placed. I started out by checking if the ItemStack is a block but it misses some items such as sugar cane, nether wart, etc. I haven't been able to find a function isPlaceable or any Interface that could be used with instanceof.

Right now I'm doing this:

```java
BlockPos blockPos = mc.objectMouseOver.getBlockPos();
ItemStack itemInUse = mc.thePlayer.getHeldItem();

if (itemInUse != null) {
    Block resultBlock = Block.getBlockFromItem(itemInUse.getItem());

    if (mc.theWorld.getBlockState(blockPos).getBlock().getMaterial() == Material.air || resultBlock == null) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Is there any function that can do what I'm trying to achieve? If not, what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: There's not really a way to tell without actually trying to place it (which you can't try and then undo). This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) though. Why exactly do you want to know this?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm making a small build utility mod. One feature is blocking any kind of placing if the height is different to the one that was set by the user to avoid misplacing blocks. Currently, due to not being able to check for items that can be placed it blocks everything which means you can't eat food while right-clicking blocks for example, even though food can't be placed. When I tried to check for blocks, it'd work but only for real blocks, not for items that can be placed such as seeds. Doesn't seem like an XY problem to me.

Comment: That's a really really fuzzy line. Does a water bucket count, since you get a water block when you right click it, but still keep a modified item? If so, does flint and steel count too? Does an eye of ender count, since it goes from your inventory into the world, even though it becomes part of an end portal frame and not a block of its own? Do armor stands, paintings, and item frames count, since they go from your inventory into the world, even though they become entities and not blocks? If so, do minecarts count too? Or mob spawn eggs for that matter?

Comment: You're right, I suppose it depends on the context. I might just avoid that altogether and keep my current solution.